# navigate to next page and get href link

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

how to navigate page to the last page and get all href link from unchanged link page?
hhere my code is:

```
url = 'https://hoaxornot.detik.com/paging#'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
pathToChromeDriver = "C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chromedriver.exe"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=pathToChromeDriver,
                           options=options)

try:
    browser.get(url)
    browser.implicitly_wait(10)
    html = browser.page_source
    page = 1
    while page <= 2:
        paging = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="number_filters"]/a[{}]'.format(page)).click()
        for p in paging:
            articles = p.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="results-search-hoax-paging"]/div/div/article/a')
            for article in articles:
                print(article.get_attribute("href"))
        page += 1
    
        
finally:
    browser.quit()
```

Comment: Just try and except break the page after you find the elements and append to an empty list.

Comment: okay noted @ArundeepChohan

Answer (score 1):

```
wait=WebDriverWait(browser,60) 
browser.get("https://hoaxornot.detik.com/paging#")
page=1
articles=[]
while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(1)
        pagearticles=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="results-search-hoax-paging"]/div/div/article/a')))
        for article in pagearticles:
            articles.append(article.get_attribute("href"))      
        page+=1
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="number_filters"]/a[{}]'.format(page)))).click()
    except:
        break
print(articles)
```

Here's a simple way to loop through the pages and wait for the element's visibility to come up so you can obtain their values instead of an empty list.

Import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
```

Outputs:

```
['https://news.detik.com/berita/d-5900248/video-jembatan-ambruk-disebut-di-samarinda-faktanya-bukan-di-indonesia', 'https://news.detik.com/berita/d-5898607/kantor-walkot-jakbar-diviralkan-rusak-akibat-gempa-ini-faktanya', 'https://news.detik.com/berita/d-5896931/polisi-di-singkawang-diviralkan-berbahasa-china-di-publik-begini-faktanya', 'https://news.detik.com/berita-jawa-timur/d-5895069/video-viral-hutan-baluran-banjir-dipastikan-hoax-polisi-itu-video-lama', 'https://news.detik.com/internasional/d-5873027/beredar-video-ledakan-parah-di-dubai-ternyata-3-insiden-lama-beda-negara', 'https://news.detik.com/berita/d-5865905/awas-ikut-tertipu-sejumlah-warga-ke-kantor-pln-bali-gegara-hoax-rekrutmen', 'https://news.detik.com/berita/d-5863802/beredar-pesan-gambar-kpk-pantau-muktamar-nu-di-lampung-ini-faktanya', 'https://news.detik.com/berita/d-5842083/viral-video-ayah-pukuli-anak-pakai-balok-kayu-begini-faktanya', 'https://news.detik.com/berita/d-5798562/video-mobil-ngebut-190-kmjam-dikaitkan-vanessa-angel-dipastikan-hoax', 'https://news.detik.com/berita/d-5755035/muncul-isu-liar-jokowi-joget-tanpa-masker-di-papua-ini-faktanya', 'https://news.detik.com/berita/d-5729500/beredar-edaran-penerima-bantuan-pesantren-kemenag-pastikan-hoax', 'https://news.detik.com/berita-jawa-timur/d-5715146/5-bersaudara-di-surabaya-butuh-diadopsi-karena-papa-mama-meninggal-covid-19-hoaks', 'https://news.detik.com/berita/d-5714873/minta-maaf-ustaz-royan-jelaskan-viral-5-polisi-angkat-poster-demo-jokowi', 'https://health.detik.com/berita-detikhealth/d-5714239/viral-bawang-putih-tarik-cairan-dari-paru-paru-pasien-corona-ini-faktanya', 'https://health.detik.com/berita-detikhealth/d-5699731/awas-hoax-viral-info-vaksin-palsu-beredar-di-indonesia-ini-faktanya', 'https://finance.detik.com/berita-ekonomi-bisnis/d-5688266/hoax-pesan-bantuan-subsidi-gaji-rp-35-juta-jangan-dibuka', 'https://news.detik.com/berita-jawa-timur/d-5658878/2-sekolah-ditolak-warga-bondowoso-jadi-tempat-isolasi-satgas-tak-patah-arang', 'https://news.detik.com/berita/d-5655368/viral-video-demo-rusuh-di-jl-gajah-mada-polisi-pastikan-hoax', 'https://news.detik.com/berita/d-5755035/muncul-isu-liar-jokowi-joget-tanpa-masker-di-papua-ini-faktanya', 'https://news.detik.com/berita/d-5729500/beredar-edaran-penerima-bantuan-pesantren-kemenag-pastikan-hoax', 'https://news.detik.com/berita-jawa-timur/d-5715146/5-bersaudara-di-surabaya-butuh-diadopsi-karena-papa-mama-meninggal-covid-19-hoaks', 'https://news.detik.com/berita/d-5714873/minta-maaf-ustaz-royan-jelaskan-viral-5-polisi-angkat-poster-demo-jokowi', 'https://health.detik.com/berita-detikhealth/d-5714239/viral-bawang-putih-tarik-cairan-dari-paru-paru-pasien-corona-ini-faktanya', 'https://health.detik.com/berita-detikhealth/d-5699731/awas-hoax-viral-info-vaksin-palsu-beredar-di-indonesia-ini-faktanya', 'https://finance.detik.com/berita-ekonomi-bisnis/d-5688266/hoax-pesan-bantuan-subsidi-gaji-rp-35-juta-jangan-dibuka', 'https://news.detik.com/berita-jawa-timur/d-5658878/2-sekolah-ditolak-warga-bondowoso-jadi-tempat-isolasi-satgas-tak-patah-arang', 'https://news.detik.com/berita/d-5655368/viral-video-demo-rusuh-di-jl-gajah-mada-polisi-pastikan-hoax', 'https://news.detik.com/berita-jawa-tengah/d-5645668/heboh-ajakan-tolak-ppkm-darurat-di-pekalongan-ini-kata-polisi', 'https://news.detik.com/berita/d-5643373/heboh-tim-covid-buru-warga-tanjungpinang-langgar-ppkm-darurat-ini-faktanya', 'https://news.detik.com/berita/d-5638774/viral-rusa-keliaran-di-jalanan-denpasar-saat-ppkm-darurat-ini-faktanya', 'https://health.detik.com/berita-detikhealth/d-5635282/deretan-hoax-air-kelapa-netralkan-vaksin-hingga-obati-covid-19', 'https://news.detik.com/berita-jawa-tengah/d-5633158/beredar-pesan-ada-pasien-corona-kabur-di-kudus-ternyata', 'https://news.detik.com/berita-jawa-tengah/d-5622194/viral-tim-sar-klaten-kewalahan-jasad-covid-belum-dimakamkan-ini-faktanya', 'https://news.detik.com/berita/d-5607406/beredar-isu-sutiyoso-meninggal-keluarga-tidak-benar', 'https://news.detik.com/berita-jawa-tengah/d-5603576/waspada-ada-akun-wa-catut-bupati-klaten-minta-sumbangan', 'https://news.detik.com/berita-jawa-tengah/d-5603472/heboh-pesan-berantai-soal-varian-baru-corona-di-kudus-ini-faktanya', 'https://news.detik.com/berita/d-5591931/beredar-poster-konvensi-capres-nu-2024-pbnu-pastikan-hoax', 'https://health.detik.com/berita-detikhealth/d-5591504/viral-hoax-makan-bawang-3-kali-sehari-sembuhkan-corona-ini-faktanya', 'https://news.detik.com/berita/d-5590632/viral-tes-antigen-pakai-air-keran-hasilnya-positif-satgas-kepri-menepis', 'https://news.detik.com/internasional/d-5586179/fakta-di-balik-aksi-penyiar-malaysia-tutup-1-mata-untuk-palestina', 'https://inet.detik.com/cyberlife/d-5585732/waspada-6-hoax-vaksin-bermagnet-hingga-china-siapkan-senjata-biologis', 'https://health.detik.com/berita-detikhealth/d-5533468/viral-jadi-sulit-ereksi-karena-vaksin-sinovac-ini-penjelasan-dokter', 'https://health.detik.com/berita-detikhealth/d-5527149/viral-cacing-di-masker-impor-dari-china-ini-fakta-di-baliknya', 'https://finance.detik.com/energi/d-5526617/viral-gaji-petugas-kebersihan-pertamina-rp-13-juta-manajemen-hoax', 'https://news.detik.com/berita-jawa-tengah/d-5519314/fakta-fakta-gibran-disebut-duduk-di-meja-menteri-pupr-duduk-di-kursi', 'https://finance.detik.com/energi/d-5511928/awas-hoax-bbm-langka-imbas-kilang-kebakaran-pertamina-stok-luber', 'https://news.detik.com/berita-jawa-tengah/d-5511550/viral-gibran-duduk-di-atas-meja-depan-menteri-basuki-begini-faktanya', 'https://news.detik.com/berita/d-5507088/geger-kaca-bus-transmetro-deli-medan-diduga-ditembak-begini-faktanya', 'https://health.detik.com/berita-detikhealth/d-5487986/viral-lansia-non-dki-bisa-vaksin-corona-di-senayan-dipastikan-hoax', 'https://finance.detik.com/berita-ekonomi-bisnis/d-5487983/awas-hoax-pesan-berantai-soal-vaksinasi-lansia-di-istora-senayan', 'https://health.detik.com/berita-detikhealth/d-5480124/hoax-tak-ada-larangan-minum-obat-jantung-sebelum-vaksin-covid-19', 'https://health.detik.com/berita-detikhealth/d-5473657/hoax-kemenkes-bantah-puluhan-wartawan-terkapar-setelah-vaksinasi-covid-19', 'https://health.detik.com/berita-detikhealth/d-5368305/minum-air-putih-bisa-atasi-kekentalan-darah-pasien-covid-19-ini-faktanya', 'https://health.detik.com/berita-detikhealth/d-5360703/viral-info-penemu-vaksin-covid-19-sinovac-meninggal-ini-faktanya', 'https://health.detik.com/berita-detikhealth/d-5357602/pasien-jalan-ngangkang-seperti-penguin-disebut-karena-anal-swab-ini-faktanya', 'https://finance.detik.com/moneter/d-5351004/kabar-bi-di-lockdown-bank-internasional-swiss-dipastikan-hoax', 'https://finance.detik.com/berita-ekonomi-bisnis/d-5350942/hoax-jangan-percaya-pesan-berantai-dana-bagi-bagi-uang-tunai', 'https://health.detik.com/berita-detikhealth/d-5340874/sederet-hoax-vaksin-jokowi-disebut-salah-suntik-hingga-tak-sampai-habis', 'https://health.detik.com/berita-detikhealth/d-5338133/hoax-viral-kasdim-0817-gresik-wafat-usai-vaksin-covid-19-ini-faktanya', 'https://health.detik.com/berita-detikhealth/d-5337075/viral-urutan-mandi-agar-tak-kena-stroke-ini-faktanya', 'https://news.detik.com/berita/d-5328895/foto-bayi-selamat-dari-sriwijaya-air-sj182-dipastikan-hoax', 'https://health.detik.com/berita-detikhealth/d-5324630/viral-vaksin-covid-19-memperbesar-penis-bpom-hoax-lah', 'https://news.detik.com/berita-jawa-timur/d-5321500/wawali-surabaya-terpilih-armuji-dikabarkan-meninggal-ketua-dprd-hoaks', 'https://news.detik.com/berita/d-5287986/beredar-chat-kapolda-metro-soal-sikat-laskar-hrs-dipastikan-hoax', 'https://news.detik.com/berita/d-5286913/video-ambulans-fpi-masuk-rs-saat-ricuh-diviralkan-ini-faktanya', 'https://news.detik.com/berita-jawa-tengah/d-5280091/viral-bendung-gerak-serayu-jebol-kepala-upt-itu-kapal-ponton-hanyut', 'https://news.detik.com/berita-jawa-tengah/d-5279872/viral-asrama-isolasi-mandiri-ugm-penuh-ternyata-begini-faktanya', 'https://news.detik.com/berita/d-5275107/kpu-makassar-bantah-keluarkan-flyer-hasil-survei-paslon-pilwalkot-berlogo-kpu', 'https://news.detik.com/berita-jawa-tengah/d-5264429/beredar-voice-note-binatang-buas-gunung-merapi-turun-ke-selo-kades-hoax', 'https://news.detik.com/berita-jawa-tengah/d-5262931/viral-peta-bahaya-gunung-merapi-sejauh-10-km-bpptkg-itu-peta-2010', 'https://health.detik.com/berita-detikhealth/d-5254580/viral-tips-sembuhkan-covid-19-dalam-waktu-5-menit-dokter-paru-pastikan-hoax', 'https://news.detik.com/berita-jawa-timur/d-5253524/video-jenazah-covid-19-diviralkan-bola-mata-hilang-keluarga-sebut-hoaks', 'https://news.detik.com/berita/d-5287986/beredar-chat-kapolda-metro-soal-sikat-laskar-hrs-dipastikan-hoax', 'https://news.detik.com/berita/d-5286913/video-ambulans-fpi-masuk-rs-saat-ricuh-diviralkan-ini-faktanya', 'https://news.detik.com/berita-jawa-tengah/d-5280091/viral-bendung-gerak-serayu-jebol-kepala-upt-itu-kapal-ponton-hanyut', 'https://news.detik.com/berita-jawa-tengah/d-5279872/viral-asrama-isolasi-mandiri-ugm-penuh-ternyata-begini-faktanya', 'https://news.detik.com/berita/d-5275107/kpu-makassar-bantah-keluarkan-flyer-hasil-survei-paslon-pilwalkot-berlogo-kpu', 'https://news.detik.com/berita-jawa-tengah/d-5264429/beredar-voice-note-binatang-buas-gunung-merapi-turun-ke-selo-kades-hoax', 'https://news.detik.com/berita-jawa-tengah/d-5262931/viral-peta-bahaya-gunung-merapi-sejauh-10-km-bpptkg-itu-peta-2010', 'https://health.detik.com/berita-detikhealth/d-5254580/viral-tips-sembuhkan-covid-19-dalam-waktu-5-menit-dokter-paru-pastikan-hoax', 'https://news.detik.com/berita-jawa-timur/d-5253524/video-jenazah-covid-19-diviralkan-bola-mata-hilang-keluarga-sebut-hoaks', 'https://news.detik.com/berita/d-3124615/benarkah-sesuap-lele-mengandung-3000-sel-kanker', 'https://news.detik.com/berita/d-3124915/loket-tiket-konser-bon-jovi-di-gbk-dibakar-hoax']
```